# Link directly to a jQuery tab from another page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

Let's begin by saying I'm skilled in HTML and CSS, but this jQuery stuff is kind of new to me.  So this might be really easy to fix and I've looked at other answers but I can't get the hang of it.

I have a jQuery tab table set up with four tabs, like so:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <a rel="tab_1">Education Insurance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="tab_2">Home Insurance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="tab_3">Car Insurance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="tab_4">Business Insurance</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The content for each tab is in a separate div tag below it, like so:

```
<div class="panes">
    <div id="tab_1" class="tab-content">
        <p>Tab content goes here.</p>
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a link on the homepage that can link directly to tab 2 or tab 3, which are on a separate page.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I wonder if you might need to create the links so that they use some Javascript to activate whatever tabs? Not sure whether you could simply link to them since the tab control is a JQuery object and not a separate page.

Comment: Are the tabs on the homepage or a different page from the link?

Comment: The tabs are on a separate page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery UI tabs, thats does that automatically.

Here is a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/v3eFa/3/)

Tab Links

[First tab](http://fiddle.jshell.net/joycse06/v3eFa/2/show/#tabs-1)

[Second tab](http://fiddle.jshell.net/joycse06/v3eFa/2/show/#tabs-2)

[Third Tab](http://fiddle.jshell.net/joycse06/v3eFa/2/show/#tabs-3)

Reference: [JQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Even better you can change the hash on select so that users can copy the url themselves like this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
    }
});

​
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...select_a_tab_from_a_text_link_instead_of_clicking_a_tab_itself) :) quite a simple snippet, I've used it myself.

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
```

If you want to do it "on load" of the page (i.e. the link on the homepage takes you to a different tabbed screen) you'd just want to pass something across in the request that the document load can decypher and use the .tabs("select", tabNo) as shown above. Again, I've done this in production code and it's reliable.

Comment: Okay, I have seen this before, but since I'm so new to jQuery I'm not sure what to do with that code.  Does it go on the page, or in a javascript file?  And do I need to create a line for each tab that needs it?  Not trying to be difficult, I just need to know what to do with it.

Comment: The snippet above selects a tab within the same page, however, stripping out the event handling (the .click line), the rest of it shows you how to access the tabs and manipulate them. You'd simply need an anchor that passes through a parameter to the other page which the document ready function could act upon to select the correct tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all the content divs are visible and you need to scroll to that particular div when the user clicks on it.
You just need to bind the button to a scroll event.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('button2').click = function (){
 $(document).scrollTo('#tab2');
 } 
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('button3').click = function (){
 $(document).scrollTo('#tab3');
 } 
 });
```

Now create two buttons with id 'button1' and 'button2'. For example.

```
<div id='button2'>Tab2</div>
or
<a href='#' id='button2'>Tab2</a>
```

When the user clicks on them he is taken to the content div.