# Link directly to a jQuery ajaxtab from another page?

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm having problems making links to ajaxtabs on another page.

I've looked at this [Link directly to a jQuery tab from another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818754/link-directly-to-a-jquery-tab-from-another-page/10818889#10818889) which is exactly what I want to do. However my content is loaded via Ajax, it also has 'stickytab' cookies as well.

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs 1.8.22, can some assist me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      ajaxOptions: {
        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
          $( anchor.hash ).html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "Please contact webmaster@tch.anu.edu.au" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".tabs").tabs();
      if($(".tabs") && document.location.hash){
        $.scrollTo(".tabs");
      }
      $(".tabs ul").localScroll({
        target:".tabs",
        duration:0,
        hash:true
      });
    });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function()
  {
    var cookieName = 'stickyTab';

    $( '#tabs' ).tabs( {
      selected: ( $.cookies.get( cookieName ) || 0 ),
      select: function( e, ui )
      {
        $.cookies.set( cookieName, ui.index );
      }
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: This jquery uses AJAX tabs loading external content into the allocated space with cookies session. 

It also makes the tab 1/2/3 linkable giving it's own URL so you can give someone your website so it will open the correct tab. This will allow you to make links on your site to these reference tab.